# How can i add a multiple Items in a ListBox on WPF application with xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listboxitems

i have this XAML code:

```
 <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNode}" 
            PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
            PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseDown" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Col}" Margin="10,0,10,10">
```

but i have to add "SelectedMobileDevice" and "SelectedNode" in the Binding property. this error is throw: any type constructor has two binding parameter.

Please help me.. thanks

Comment: Question needs more information. Do you want to bind two properties to SelectedItem? If yes, try MultiBinding with MultiConverter.

Comment: Please can you write an example?